# Discord.js trying to DM a user when they get banned

Tags: discord.js

Hello so I'm trying to DM a user with my discord bot when they get banned but this message appears in the logs every time I ban a user:

```
2020-06-24T18:55:42.825881+00:00 app[worker.1]: Unhandled promise rejection: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825916+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825918+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825918+00:00 app[worker.1]:   method: 'post',

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825919+00:00 app[worker.1]:   path: '/channels/725422295631396876/messages',

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825920+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 50007,

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825921+00:00 app[worker.1]:   httpStatus: 403

2020-06-24T18:55:42.825921+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

Currently this is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Bans a member.',
    usage: '[mention]',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);
                if (member) {
                    user.send("You we're banned from Jakooobs Cat House!")
                  member
                    .ban({
                      reason: 'BANNED!',
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                      message.reply(`Successfully banned ${user.tag}`);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                      message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
                      console.error(err);
                    });
                } else {
                  message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
                }
              } else {
                message.reply("You didn't mention the user to ban!");
              }
            }
          
        else {
            message.reply('you don\'t have permission to ban members!')
        }
    },
};
```

I looked on internet but I didn't find anything so if someone knows the aswer then please reply thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member.send()` is an async method so it doesn't wait to send the message and then ban, so you can either use await or `.then`, since you are already using .then you might aswell just chain the promises like so:

```js
if (member) {
    user.send("You we're banned from Jakooobs Cat House!")
        //incase bot can't dm user
        .catch(() => message.reply("Unable to send message to user"))
        .then(() => member.ban({ reason: "BANNED!" }))
        .then(() => message.reply(`Successfully banned ${user.tag}`))
        .catch(err => {
            message.reply('I was unable to ban the member');
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: You should add a .catch at `user.send()`. It may return an error depending on the user's privacy settings.

Comment: The key thing to note is that it's returning the promises, so that if the promise rejects, then it will return the rejection and it will go to the catch block I have at the end. As such `user.send`, `member.ban`, `message.reply` will all be covered by the single catch block

Comment: But since that one single catch block covers all the promises, if it fails on the `user.send` then it won't get to the `.then` where it actually bans the member, will edit answer